# Clearing Chache For Parked Domains

Tags: caching

I am using boost for cache my website. the website can be accessed through multiple parked domains. When I clear all caches by accessing my admin area through one domain it clears the cached pages accessed through that domain. But when I visit a site through other domains it still shows the cached site.

Under public_html/cache/normal there is a list of folders for all domains.

Comment: Have you tested in separate machines? It looks like a browser cache issue to me. Try hitting [Ctrl] + [F5] to do a full refresh, that should clear the browser cache.

Comment: My customer me and some other people having same issue from different geographical locations